# Next App Directory Share a common layout between `app` and `pages`

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've been thinking about migrating my app to use partially the new Next App Directory and I aware that the Pages folder can work with the new App Directory.

However all my pages share the same layout, so I was wondering how could both RSC and Pages work together sharing a common layout with a simple project.

The navigation "works", however it's causing all the pages that live in the `pages` folder to fully reload when I navigate to them.

See the following gif:

Note that `Home` and `Legal` are RSC and `FAQ` and `About` are pages components.

[image: navigation]

Initially I thought that it was related to the DOM reconciliation where the Virtual DOM doesn't match the real DOM thus causing a full reload. However the full reload happens even when I navigate to a page that is already loaded.

My layout.tsx file

```
// src/app/layout.tsx
import CommonLayout from '@/components/layouts/common'
import './globals.css'

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <CommonLayout>
      {children}
    </CommonLayout>
  )
}
```

the CommonLayout.tsx file

```
// src/components/layouts/common.tsx
import Navbar from "./navbar";

export default function CommonLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <head />
      <body className='p-10'>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

and the Navbar.tsx file which simply has a list of links and uses the Link component from Next

```
// src/components/layouts/navbar.tsx
"use client";
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav className='navbar'>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link className='text-red-500' href='/'>Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link className='text-blue-500' href='/legal'>Legal</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link className='text-green-500' href='/faq'>FAQ</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link className='text-pink-500' href='/about'>About</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

This is my current directory structure:

[image: app structure]

Here's the [full sample project](https://github.com/esponges/layout-next-13).